# Youtube Overlay Image Div - Autoplay Underneath

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, onclick, overlay

I have a div overlay on top of a YouTube iframe on this [homepage](http://www.belfastdigitalagency.com).

The idea is you click once and then the video would automatically play, however I just can't get it to play ball.  When I set YouTube paramater 'autoplay=1' the video plays underneath the image without even clicking it.

Here's the code I'm using below;

```
<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
thevid.style.display='block'; 
this.style.display='none'">

<img style="cursor: pointer;"
src="http://www.belfastdigitalagency.com/wp-content/themes/responsy-v2.5/random_image1.php"
alt="belfast digital marketing agency animated video" />
</div>

<div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">
<iframe width="1280" height="720"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iy_lolGhjPE?rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&theme=light&showinfo=0&origin=http://www.belfastdigitalagency.com"
frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always"
allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?  Much appreciated in advance, even if it's just a pointer to check out something that looks bad!

Cheers,

Phil

P.S - thanks to the legend that is [UnLoCo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179545/unloco), it's fixed in no time. Here's the final code to correct. Thanks again UnLoCo!

```
<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'; 
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 
document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');">

<img style="cursor: pointer;" src="http://www.belfastdigitalagency.com/wp-content/themes/responsy-v2.5/random_image1.php" alt="belfast digital marketing agency animated video" />
</div>

<div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">
<iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iy_lolGhjPE?rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&theme=light&showinfo=0&origin=http://www.belfastdigitalagency.com"
frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on click, add:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 
document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');
```

Comment: Thanks UnLoCo, could you please put that in layman terms for me?  I'm new to the game!

Comment: Hi, this bit of code replaces the autoplay=0 on the iframe src attribute with autoplay=1; meaning that it will make the iframe reload and play automatically.

Comment: is this what you mean? '<iframe src='about:blank'></iframe>' then Youtube link?

Comment: ah ok, the thing I just can't understand is how to have a blank iframe src, then have Youtube as the src.  Do I make 2 iframe, or have 2 src destinations? Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: No don't go with that, as i said i changed my answer. i explained it on the second comment.

Comment: Sorry dude, I didn't see the code come up I needed to refresh! First time on Stack Overflow. I've updated my attempt above, am I nearly there?  I just can't get the final click working, I must have used the syntax wrong.

Comment: yeah sorry, replace `"` with `'` around `("iframe")` and any other occurences

Comment: boom you're a legend! working perfectly. thank you so much, really appreciate the help UnLoCo! :) p.s. I will vote up when I get suffice points to!