# youtube autoload after image click - Chrome/Opera

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, embed, opera

i've a code which let start a youtubevideo after clicking on a image.
The Problem is, that Opera, Chrome ect. start the video behind the image before clicking.
Firefox works fine.

Heres my code:

```
<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
    <img style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 89px;" src="./img/style/new/slider/XXXXXX.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="604" height="266" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXX?rel=0&autohide=2&showinfo=0&controls=0&modestbranding=0&wmode=transparent&showsearch=0&version=3&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Can you help me for a better code?
Additional is it possible to show the Image again after the video ends?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: push

Answer (score 0):

What if you paste the iframe code to #thevideo when the user clicks the image?
I think you can use the .append() function in jQuery to do it.

Comment: .append() to reshow the image after the video ends?
And whats with the code to fix the chrome/opera problem?

Answer (score 0):

The chrome/opera...browser issue is a known issue. There are browser settings that you can change that will make it so that it does not auto play the video, since you are really just putting a mask over the video. See this article: [Stop youtube autoplay](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/stop-youtube-autoplay/)

EDIT:
To handle it with a programmatic approach:
change your autoplay value in the youtube url to "autoplay=0". Add an id value to your iframe, such as id="iframe". Then add the following line of code to the click function of your image: document.getElementById('iframe').src = document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');

This can also be seen at: [Youtube Overlay Image Div - Autoplay Underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995529/youtube-overlay-image-div-autoplay-underneath)

Comment: Yeah, but i dont want, that all of my website visitors must change theire browser settings before they can use my website correctly do you know?

Ist there no chance to fix it from the website?

Answer (score 0):

See above:

EDIT: To handle it with a programmatic approach: change your autoplay value in the youtube url to "autoplay=0". Add an id value to your iframe, such as id="iframe". Then add the following line of code to the click function of your image: document.getElementById('iframe').src = document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');

This can also be seen at: Youtube Overlay Image Div - Autoplay Underneath

I used it and it works great!